# PrimeFaces Charts not visible when included by another page

Tags: jsf, charts, primefaces, render

Brand new to JSF, but I understand the lifecycle. I am using JSF 2.2, Primefaces 6.1. I created a layout separtely in an xhtml page called bDashboard.xhtml. Works fine when called directly. But when I include it in a different page via `<ui:include src="/bDashboard.xhtml" />` the charts are not rendered. Here is the dashboard file:

```
<ui:composition  
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf" 
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:ct="http://www.chartistjsf.org/charts"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">


<h3>My Dashboard</h3>
<p:panelGrid columns="2" layout="grid">
    <p:panel>
        <p:chart type="pie" model="#{pieChartBean.pieModel1}"
            style="display:block;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;" />
    </p:panel>
    <p:panel>
        <p:chart type="pie" model="#{pieChartBean.pieModel2}" visible="true"
            style="display:block;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;" />
    </p:panel>
  </p:panelGrid>
</ui:composition>
```

This above file is included thus:

```
<h:form id="buyerDashForm">
            <ui:include src="/bDashboard.xhtml" />
</h:form>
```

Piechart Managed Bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class PieChartBean {
    private PieChartModel pieModel1;
    private PieChartModel pieModel2;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    createPieModels();
}

public PieChartModel getPieModel1() {
    return pieModel1;
}

public PieChartModel getPieModel2() {
    return pieModel2;
}

private void createPieModels() {
    createPieModel1();
    createPieModel2();
}

private void createPieModel1() {
    pieModel1 = new PieChartModel();

    pieModel1.set("Kajaria Builders", 540);
    pieModel1.set("Bajaj Constructions", 325);
    pieModel1.set("Sentinel Builders", 702);
    pieModel1.set("Regency Towers", 421);

    pieModel1.setTitle("Savings By Project");
    pieModel1.setLegendPosition("w");
    pieModel1.setShadow(false);
}

private void createPieModel2() {
    pieModel2 = new PieChartModel();

    pieModel2.set("Kajaria Builders", 50);
    pieModel2.set("Bajaj Constructions", 35);
    pieModel2.set("Sentinel Builders", 72);
    pieModel2.set("Regency Towers", 41);


    pieModel2.setTitle("Savings By Spend Category");
    pieModel2.setLegendPosition("e");
    pieModel2.setShowDataLabels(true);
    pieModel2.setShadow(false);
}
```

I receive no errors when the page is rendered.

Comment: Hi, a couple of things, first always try to create a [mcve] to narrow down your problem and make it easier to read for us. Secondly, don't add a `<h:body>` in included files, and 3rd you have nested forms. The 2nd one might be related to your problem

Comment: Hi @Kukeltje, I have removed all the extraneous tags and moved the panelgrids into <ui:composition>, yet the problem persists. I have edited my code above. Also removed all the forms.

Comment: Please, still waay too much code there. Or does it actually work if you remove any of the remaining tags? Please learn about [mcve]

Comment: I have removed all the cruft...yet there seems to be a problem.

Comment: No client-side (javascript) errors either? And removing the panelgrid makes it work? And what about the style of the charts? Can those be removed?

Comment: Tried everything...just doesn't render @Kukeltje.

Comment: I tried someting similar (similar, most likely not identical since you still did not post an [mcve] and I tried with 6.2 and 6.3-SNAPSHOT) and for me it works. Please make it a REAL [mcve] and try 6.2code? Please dp

Comment: Hi @Kukeltje, unfortunately the project is boxed in Primefaces 6.1

Comment: Anyway I moved on to ChartistJSF...which seems to work well. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Boxed in PF 6.1 but a new library is allowed? Hmmm strange. And PF 6.3 will get new charts as well. But you problem might be more generic. Next time, please, please, please create a [mcve].

Comment: @Kukeltje I am working on only a module of the project. They have both Primefaces 6.1 and ChartistJSF 3 as dependencies. I wanted all the charts by Primefaces. When I tried using 6.2 the program mal-behaved. So I had to move to ChartistJSF. Thanks again for your patience. I will make a better MCVE next time.

Answer (score 0):

I believe chart component works in primeface 6.1 as well.
I ran the above code snippet that you have posted including .xhtml template,it worked fine here.

-> I removed visible=true from .xhtml file.
->Also ensure location of the template file specified in ui:include

My pom.xml looks like this

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- JSF -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Below is the output
[image]

Comment: Actually it works well as a separate file, just doesn't seem to show up when included in another file.

Comment: @mallikkumar: all this shows you have things not visible in your Q that play a role in your problem!